# Magento 2 : How to call phtml file in helper?

Tags: magento2

I got asnwer of how to call it in Magento 1, but in M2 i am getting an error.

```
if($product->getTest()){
        $productid = $product->getId();
        return Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('demo/test/test.phtml');
    }
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **try this code**

```
protected $layoutFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...................................
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
    ...................................
) {
    ...................................
    $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    ...................................
}

public function getPHtmlFile()
{

    $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
    $blockOption = $layout->createBlock("Your Block path")->setTemplate('Vendorename_Modulename::Yourphtmlfile.phtml')
    return $blockOption->toHtml();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
protected $_resultPageFactory;
...
public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
   ...
) {
   ...
   $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
   ...
}

//method
public function getStaticBlock()
   {
       $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
       return $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::example.phtml")->toHtml();
   }
```

Happy coding